# How Can I Unpack a z8 file?

Tags: translation, unpack, z-machine

http://www.ifcomp.org/1418/content/index.html

I was try to translate this game into my own language, but the sources was packed to a z-code game file(*.z8), Is there any way view and change the sources?

My english is really poor ,I had try Google but only find this 
http://babel.ifarchive.org/

where can I get the unpack tool? reading english is too hard for me...

Or, if there is other way of translate this game will be great

Comment: A .z8 file is not a "package" you could unpack. It's (virtual) machine code and you can't turn it into original source any more than you could an .exe file for example. There are tools to reverse the machine code into Inform 6 code but it won't be much help.

Comment: In any case, if you want to translate the game you should ask the author for the source code. You need to ask for permission for the translation anyway.

Comment: thank you ,I will send e-mail to him^_^